# What is the proper name for the 2016 edition of Traveller by Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose-traveller-2

A new edition of *Traveller* by Mongoose was released in early 2016. What is the proper name for it if I want to distinguish it from other versions of *Traveller*. Is it *Mongoose Traveller, 2nd Edition*? Or does it have some other name?

The cover is no help, but I'm wondering if it's like *Dungeons & Dragons, 5th Edition* where the cover doesn't say it's 5th Edition, but the title page does say it.

(I do realize that our RPG.SE tag is "mongoose-traveller-2", but I figure there is a more authoritative source than that).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is officially just "[Traveller](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/171643/Traveller-Core-Rulebook?affiliate_id=7242)."

Mongoose simply uses "[New Traveller](http://www.mongoosepublishing.com/rpgs/traveller-1.html)" on their product Web site to distinguish it from the older products, which are listed as "Last Chance to Buy Traveller!". Clearly not a branding term.

[On their product forums](http://forum.mongoosepublishing.com/), it's one forum for all editions and where applicable on a question posters just say "1e" or "2e."

It is not uncommon nowadays for subsequent game editions to be not branded differently at all by the publisher.